# Object creation using NSNumber literals

Tags: objective-c, literals, nsnumber

what is the difference between these two approaches for objection creation?

1. `NSNumber *aInt= @54;`
2. `NSNumber *aInt= [NSNumber numberWithInt:54];`

I know that first approach is NSNumber literal and second is NSNumber class methods. Both are used to create an NSNumber object. But which approach is better?
if i creates object using literal style then how memory is allocated to it? How it is differ then second approach? Please suggest me some key point about these concepts so that i prefer better approach to create NSNumber object.

I know that object created at runtime. Does literals objects are also created at runtime? please provide some essential key points to clear my doubt.

Comment: "But which approach is better?" – please, **don't.** Just don't ask questions like this. They miserably lack any and all context. Better **for what?** Which language is better, Python or English? It all depends. For programming, Python. For writing poems, English. Similarly, the object literal is shorter, more legible, but the explicit method call is backwards-compatible with older compilers.

Answer (score 2):

They are identical. In fact they are translated to the same code during compilation.

I always go for the literal because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between these two approaches for objection
>   creation?

They are Identical.

Answers for:

No. 1:

Using `@`-prefix will automatically wrap scalar types like `int` or `float`.

No. 2:

Using `numberWith[type]` creates NSNumber specifically and therefor easy to distinguish.

I'm not really sure about memory management of it, but i think, talking about memory allocation it's just the same.

---

I personally use `numberWith[type]` because it's more distinguishable (for me), i mean the types it holds and i dont have to worry about backward compatibility, but still i have the knowledge about the literals so i dont have any issue using it.

Better approach is very hard to answer, it's completely up to you/to the developer.

You might also want to check this [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/)

And please, avoid asking too many questions in one post. Cheers! :)